# How to write to DLQ?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I am currently trying to handle DeadLetterQueue messages.
How can I write a message to a DLQ?
I tried the following:

```
{
  "type": "serviceBus",
  "name": "outputSbMsg",
  "queueName": "dlq-test",
  "connection": "bus",
  "accessRights_": "Manage",
  "direction": "out"
}
```

But when I write to mySbMsg, I get the following error:

> Cannot directly create a client on a sub-queue. Create a client on the main queue and use that to create receivers on the appropriate sub-queue.

How can I write to a DLQ (preferably using node)?

Comment: So are you trying to read from or write to DLQ?

Comment: I try to write to a DLQ. I copied the wrong function.json, sorry. Reading from the DLQ is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't write an arbitrary message directly to Service Bus DLQ.

This is not related to Azure Functions. Normally, a C# service bus client would

1. Dequeue a message from a queue.
2. If message processing fails, it would either throw exception, call `BrokeredMessage.Abandon()` or `BrokeredMessage.DeadLetter()`.
3. Each one of those may move the message to DLQ (potentially after several re-tries).

Now, this doesn't change much in the context of C# Azure Functions

1. You create an `in` binding which gets a message from a queue.
2. If processing fails, you throw an exception, or call `BrokeredMessage.Abandon()` or `BrokeredMessage.DeadLetter()` explicitly, if needed.
3. The message is moved to DLQ (potentially after several re-tries).

Now, in Node you don't have `BrokeredMessage` class. But you can still throw error. If you want the message to move to DLQ after the first error, set the `Max Delivery Count` property of your service bus queue to `1`.

Comment: Thank you. In the documentation it says: "An application can also explicitly push messages to the DLQ", so I thought I could do this in node as well.